# Is there a way to increase font size in a contentEditable div in webKit?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

contentEditable still has many many browser incompatibilities, but I figured I would give it a shot and am using it a big in a web application I am developing. While working with it, I found a bunch of options that can be called via execCommand. contentEditable for Firefox lets you call

```
document.execCommand("increasefontsize",bool,value);
```

and

```
document.execCommand("decreasefontsize",bool,value);
```

to change the font size by one point. Most other major browsers, particularly WebKit do not support this and instead you have to set a specific font size. Is there a way to get around this / hack to have increasefontsize work in WebKit? Or is there a way to upon selection, get the size of the current text?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: curious - what is the output html of those commands? does it just change inline style?

Comment: also - use rangy if you're not already :) http://rangy.googlecode.com/

Comment: @MorganTiley It's a non-standard command that wraps the selection in `<big>` or `<small>` (or removes the opposite tag as appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

jwysiwyg seems to use the following code:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
    this.editorDoc.execCommand('increaseFontSize', false, null);
} else if ($.browser.safari) {
    var newNode = this.editorDoc.createElement('big');
    this.getInternalRange().surroundContents(newNode);
} else {
    console.error("Internet Explorer?");
}
```

jHtmlArea seems to use the following code:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    this.ec("fontSize", false, this.qc("fontSize") + 1)
} else if ($.browser.safari) {
    this.getRange().surroundContents($(this.iframe[0].contentWindow.document.createElement("span")).css("font-size", "larger")[0])
} else {
    this.ec("increaseFontSize", false, "big")
}
```

Sorry but I can't find definitive links for either of the above.